# Search Javascript function is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

The search function keeps giving me

Uncaught ReferenceError: finddesiredspot is not definedonclick @ (index):268

I tried everything even shifted the script around from head to body nothing works. Any idea?

Here's the javascript

```
var panos = [
              {% for group in project.panoGroups %}{% for pano in group.panos %}
        { id:"{{pano.tourId}}" , name:"{{pano.description.name}}", description:"{{pano.description.description|striphtmltags}}", thumb:"./{{dataDirectory}}/{{pano.thumbnailPath}}" },
              {% endfor %}{% endfor %}
            ];
            function resetsearch() {
                document.getElementById('resultDiv').style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById('texttosearch').innerHTML = "";
            }
function finddesiredspot() {
                if (texttosearch.value == "")
                {
                    alert("Empty string");
                    return;
                }
                var found = false;
                var foundpanos = [];
                for (i = 0; i < panos.length; i++) {
                        if (kindofsearch.value == "name")
                        {
                            if (panos[i].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(texttosearch.value.toLowerCase()) > -1)
                            {
                                found = true;
                                foundpanos.push(panos[i]);
                            }
                        }
                        if (kindofsearch.value == "description")
                        {
                            if (panos[i].description.toLowerCase().indexOf(texttosearch.value.toLowerCase()) > -1)
                            {
                                found = true;
                                foundpanos.push(panos[i]);
                            }
                        }
                }
                if (found)
                {
                    if (foundpanos.length == 1)
                    {
                        document.getElementById('resultDiv').style.display = "none";

                        var callstr = "mainloadscene(" + foundpanos[0].id + ")";
                        getTemplateTourPlayer().call(callstr);
                        callstr = "looktohotspot(" + foundpanos[0].id + ")";
                        getTemplateTourPlayer().call(callstr);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        document.getElementById('resultDiv').style.display = "block";

                        var resultsStr = "<div class='list-group'>";
                        for (i = 0 ; i < foundpanos.length ; i++)
                        {
                            resultsStr += "<a href='#' class='list-group-item' onclick=\"getTemplateTourPlayer().call('mainloadscene(" + foundpanos[i].id + ")');\"><img class='list-item-thumb' src=\""+ foundpanos[i].thumb + "\"/><strong>" + foundpanos[i].name + "</strong>";
                        }
                        resultsStr += "</ul>";
                        document.getElementById('resultList').innerHTML = resultsStr;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                        document.getElementById('resultDiv').style.display = "block";
                        document.getElementById('resultList').innerHTML = "No Result found";
                }
            }
```

And here's the HTML

```
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" id="texttosearch" class="form-control" placeholder="Text to search">
<span class="input-group-btn">
<button id="searchbutton" type="button" onclick="finddesiredspot()" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: With just that code, it seems you have errors. For instants, texttosearch.value is not defined. One not so clean workaround would be to define your function on the window object to debug it like so : window.finddesiredspot  = function()  and then call it by "window.finddesiredspot()"

Comment: This is from a program called Kolor for generating a panoramic website so the tech support gave me this search function to include it in the HTML file but it seems that they would probably need tech support.
Thank you!

Comment: I updated the code if you mind checking it again!